# Is using phusion/baseimage still worth it?

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, docker, phusion

My question is simple: why use `phusion/baseimage`?

I've read the site. I've been all over it. It's marketed as better than base, ultraslim built specifically for Docker. With that said: then why aren't official builds using it by now?

`phusion/baseimage` been out for a while now, but official builds for php, mysql, etc, are still using debian or ubuntu directly... Why?

I'm not finding any simple docker-esque (single instances) packages that inherit themselves from phusion/baseimage. php7 and nginx uses debian:jessie directly. mysql uses ubuntu.

The whole point of `phusion/baseimage` is to get away from full bloated based "VM" containers.

So, my question again: is using `phusion/baseimage` still worthwhile?

Answer (score 10):

Reasons to consider:

- I personally don't want to put all the `packages` in my `docker image` unless I
  know I need them. Example `SSH Server` in `PHP7` or `Nginx` that you
  mentioned. It's not a `vm`, it's a `container`.
- Looks like they are trying to make a `container` like a full `VM`, long 
  running with `multi services`. `Docker` philosophy is using
  `microservices`, and separate them in multiple `containers`, This has many advantages like: fault isolation, easier upgrades, scaling, etc.
- Fixes `APT`: This fix is in official ubuntu image too.
- These kind of images come with alot of complications, and remove the simplicity of `microservices design`. I'm sure it will get in your way.

I recommend using `library images` for known technologies, ie. `PHP`, `Apache`, etc. Using this + `microservices` will help your greatly long term. Now if you want to make your own images, I recommend using `library` `base images` like `alpine`, for being lightweight, or `debian` because amost all library images are based on them.

You have another option called `scratch`:

You can use `Docker`’s reserved, `minimal image`, `scratch`, as a starting point for building `containers`. Using the `scratch` image signals to the build process that you want the next command in the `Dockerfile` to be the `first filesystem layer` in your `image`.

While `scratch` appears in `Docker`’s repository on the `hub`, you can’t `pull` it, run it, or tag any image with the name `scratch`. Instead, you can refer to it in your `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM scratch
...
```

Comment: What do you recommend? I'm all ears. I'm planning on running my personal site off docker images, and I'm researching the best route to take.

Comment: I recommend using library images for known technologies, ie. `PHP`, `Apache`, etc. Using this + `microservices` will help your greatly long term. Now if you want to make your own images, I recommend using library base images like `alpine`, for  being lightweight, or `debian` because amost all library images are based on them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure phusion's mission is to reduce bloat -- it's always been bloated.

Back when I started messing with docker, the ecosystem was much, much smaller.  Phusion was an interesting image that demonstrated multiple services running within a single container, a functioning SSH server for remote access (way before it was easier to jump inside a running container).

Debian/Ubuntu are great for running a stable server.   They are horribly bloated for a container/service.

At the moment, as an IT professional -- I see no compelling reason to use phusion, except perhaps for some learning.  I would much rather own/understand my container.

Comment: "[Debian/Ubuntu] are horribly bloated for a container/service." -- "I would much rather own/understand my container." -- Then what are you using? You have to start off with a FROM.

Comment: You can start `FROM scratch` with static binaries. [Go](https://golang.org/) suits this kind of setup.

Comment: I use alpine linux when possible.

Comment: This reads more as a comment than an answer.